# html navigation convert in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I do dynamic html in wordpress? I am using this code but not able to correct , please resolve this issue anyone ?

```
<?php $navcheck = wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Top-Menu', 'theme_location' => 'Top-Menu','container_id' => 'navbarNav','container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="navbar-nav">%3$s</ul>' ) ); ?> 

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">Home</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/the-school">The School</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/english-courses">English Courses</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/study-abroad">Study Abroad</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/university-programme">University Programme</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/useful-info">Useful Info</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
</li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic html" here? What exactly are you trying to do  and what is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: do you want add class in li ?